# How to parse date format from std::cin into stringstream buffer in c++?

Tags: c++, regex, buffer, istream

Having this class:

*date.hpp*:

```
#ifndef DATE_HPP
#define DATE_HPP

#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Date
{
    std::stringstream format;
    time_t date;
    struct tm *date_tm;

public:
    Date() : date(time(NULL)), date_tm(localtime(&date)) {}
    Date(std::istream &in);
    Date(std::string str);

    const std::string getDate();
    const bool dateMatch(std::string str);
};

#endif //DATE_HPP
```

And this ctors: *date.cpp*:

```
#include "date.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool isDate(std::string target)
{
    std::regex reg("[1-12]{2}/[1-31]{2}[00-99]{2}");
    return std::regex_search(target, reg);
}

Date::Date(std::istream &in)
{
    date_tm = new struct tm;
    std::cout << "enter date [mm/dd/yy]: ";
    format.basic_ios::rdbuf(in.rdbuf());

    if (isDate(format.str()))
    {
        format >> std::get_time(date_tm, "%m/%d/%y");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Format of date is not valid\n";
    }
}
...
```

If I try to use the ctor with `std::istream` argument:

```
#include "date.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date d(cin);
    cout << d.getDate() << '\n';
}
```

Then the date format checks fails even before I can something write to cin. What is wrong now?

Comment: Oh boy, don't write to `cout` in constructors like that, please. What if you need to instantiate a `Date` from a stream other than `cin` like a file stream?

Comment: Well how other should i warn the user of ill-format of date ?

Comment: I meant mostly the prompt `std::cout << "enter date [mm/dd/yy]: ";`. Error conditions can be signaled by an exception or a status code. The calling code can decide what to do in that case, such as write an error message.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're format should be `"%m/%d/%Y"`. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time . Also your regex is missing a `'/'`. Plus your regex number ranges aren't quite right; they match a character class, not a number. `"[1-12]"` I think matches the one-character strings `"1"` and `"2"` only. You need to do something different with number ranges. You can check if the date parsing failed by checking whether `format.fail()` is `true` instead of running a regex. Plus I am skeptical of you're method of initializing `format`. It'd be better, I think, to just write

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
std::stringstream format(s);
```

.